# seems that login-page is reloading after false form-validation

Tags: php, jquery, authentication

I was changing my loginpage and I've put the jquery with the form-validation in a separate file instead of on the page itself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#confirm").on("click", function(e){
       e.PreventDefault();

        var check = true;
        var empty_fields = ['name','password'];

        for (i=0; i<empty_fields.length; i++) {
            var $field = $('#'+empty_fields[i]);

            if ($.trim($field.val()) == '') {
                $field.addClass('error');
            check = false;
            } 
            else {
                $field.removeClass('error');
            }            
        }

        if (check == true)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',              
                url: 'PHPCalls.php?CallID=Login',
                data: $("#loginform").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {                    
                    var result = $.trim(data);
                    if(result == 'true') {
                        alert('succeeded');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Before the part where I do my check on the input being empty was on the login-page itself and worked fine. I called it with an onclick="return check_form();" and then returned the value 'check' being true or false.

Since I've put this script in a separate file it seems like the page is reloading itself. When I click on the confirm-button the input-boxes get the error-layout but then the page flashes and all is set back to normal...I have no clue what is happening...

Anyone can set me on the right track?

This is a stripped part of the login-page

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajaxLogin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sha512.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/forms.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginform" class="loginform" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input username"  placeholder="Name" onfocus="this.value=''" />
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="input password"  placeholder="Wachtwoord" onfocus="this.value=''" />
    <input type="submit" id="confirm" value="Login" class="button" />
</form>
</body>
```

SOLUTION: add PreventDefault() and remove formhash()

Comment: <<I called it with an onclick="return check_form();">> checkForm() method should return false. Or you could prevent default behaviour of submit button. Hard to help without seeing all relevant code

Comment: What is formhash? What is check_form()? Why there is no `onclick="return check_form();"` in you relevant HTML markup like you said before? Have you tried just preventing default behaviour from #confirm click: `$("#confirm").on("click", function(e){e.preventDefault(); /*code here*/});`

Comment: @A.Wolff : formhash is where I hash the input so I don't send them as plain text. Even removed, it doesn't solve the problem. I do not use the onclick-event anymore cause I now call the form-validation by `$(#confirm).on("click", function(){});` Before that, I had the same function on the page itself as `function check_form() {...}`

Comment: Ok, makes more sense now ;) Still try preventing default behaviour of submit button: `$("#confirm").on("click", function(e){e.preventDefault(); /*code here*/});` This will stop FORM to be submitted

Comment: @A.Wolff : is that the same then like adding `$("#loginform").submit(function() { return false; });` above the ´on("click")` ?

Comment: Not really the same (don't stop propagation) but in your case should have same behaviour i guess

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false if check! = true

Comment: But do I need to return anything? What I do now is checking the fields on being empty with a for-loop after I clicked the button. If the field is empty, add error-class, if not, remove error-class.

Comment: return false will stop the default behaviour of form submission.  So you would add it into your code, eg `if ($.trim($field.val()) == '') {
                $field.addClass('error');
            check = false; return false;
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
if (check == true)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',              
            url: 'PHPCalls.php?CallID=Login',
            data: $("#loginform").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {                    
                var result = $.trim(data);
                if(result == 'true') {
                    alert('succeeded');
                }
            }
        });
    }
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Try this